# Show that the n-rowed determinant is always equal to $cos(n\theta)$ through induction and trig addition formulas

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, induction

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\cos\theta & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & & 0\\
1 & 2\cos\theta & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 &&0\\
0 & 1 & 2\cos\theta & 1 &&&&0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2\cos\theta &&&&0 \\
&&&.& .&&&.\\
&&&.&& .&&.\\
&&&.&&& .&.\\
 & & & & & & 2\cos\theta & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2\cos\theta \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

$Hint$: Expand using elements of the last row or column. Use mathematical induction
and the trigonometric addition formulas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_n$ denote the $n \times n$ matrix of the above form.
Verify $\det A_n = \cos(n\theta)$ for the cases $n=1,2$.

For $n \ge 3$, use the hint to show
$$\det A_n = (2\cos \theta)\det (A_{n-1}) - \det (A_{n-2}).$$
and use induction.

---

We have
\begin{align}
\det A_n
&= 2 \cos \theta \cos((n-1)\theta) - \cos((n-2)\theta).
\end{align}

Then use the identity $$2 \cos \alpha \cos \beta = \cos(\alpha-\beta) + \cos (\alpha + \beta)$$
on the first term.

Comment: Yes I found out that after taking the first cofactor out, the matrix shrinks to n-1 but where am I supposed to use the trig addition, I don't get how the trig helps me reach cos(n\theta)

Comment: Oh I see, eureka!